# Formatting the top bar

Tags: formatting, draw, addlines

I don't fully understand how to draw the following lines that are on the top and bottom of the image below:

[image]

I don't need help formatting the text, just the lines at the top and bottom.

I think I have to use a series of the `hrule` and `vrule` commands, but I'm not quite sure if this is the correct way and I cannot get things to line up the way I want them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\overbracket` and `\underbracket` commands from the package `mathtools`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbracket{\overbracket{%
\begin{array}{ll}
  \Gamma \vdash \diamond & \text{$\Gamma$ is a well-formed environment}
\end{array}
}}
\]
\[
\underbracket[0.5pt]{\overbracket[0.5pt]{%
\begin{array}{ll}
  \Gamma \vdash \diamond & \text{$\Gamma$ is a well-formed environment}
\end{array}
}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...I'm both flabbergasted and embarrassed that I couldn't find this on my own.  Thank you.